# How to easily disable invisible fields in a dijit/layout/TabContainer?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm currently using a TabContainer to display several sets of fields for a data search.
Like:

```
    <form id="my_form" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="doLayout: false">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Search by BU'">
                <p class="fieldrow">
                    <label for="codeBU_BU" class="longlabel">Business Unit</label>
                    <input id="codeBU_BU" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="required: true, maxHeight: 420">
                    <label for="userCore" class="longlabel" >User Code</label>
                    <input id="userCore" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="required: false, maxHeight: 420">
                </p>
                <p class="fieldrow">
                    <label for="from_BU" class="longlabel">From</label>
                    <input id="from_BU" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
                    <label for="to_BU" class="longlabel">To</label>
                    <input id="to_BU" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Search by CN'">
                <p class="fieldrow">
                    <label for="caseNumber" class="longlabel">Case Number</label>
                    <input id="caseNumber" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="required: true">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Search by User'">
                <p class="fieldrow">
                    <label for="userNumber" class="longlabel">User Number</label>
                    <input id="userNumber" maxlength="20" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="required: true">
                    <label for="userName" class="longlabel">User Name</label>
                    <input id="userName" maxlength="20" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox">
                </p>
                <p class="fieldrow">
                    <label for="from_US" class="longlabel">From</label>
                    <input id="from_US" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
                    <label for="to_US" class="longlabel">To</label>
                    <input id="to_US" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
                </p>
                <p class="fieldrow">
                    <label for="codeBU_US" class="longlabel">Business Unit</label>
                    <input id="codeBU_US" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="required: false, maxHeight: 420">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="my_reset" type="reset" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">New Search</button>
        <button id="my_search" type="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Search</button>
    </form>
```

The problem is when I call `form.validate()`, it does not validate because there are incorrect (empty) fields in the unselected tabs.
I thought (as I had previously encountered this in ExtJS) that invisible fields - i.e. graphically  *hidden* (not like in `<input type="hidden">`) - are not submitted/validated. This is not the case.

So, I'm asking you if there is an easy way to disable all the fields from the other tabs.
Or maybe you know how I should do to only validate the *visible* fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All the tabs are included inside the form. So, form.validate() will validate all fields (irrespective of tabs). If validation has to done selectively, we can do it manually.

```
var fields = dijit.byId('contentPanetTabID').getDescendants();
fields.forEach(function(fld){
 var t = fld.validate && !fld.validate(); //bcos not all fields have validate method
 if(t){ //if invalid
   //display message or do something
 }
});
```